# Imagemagick producing poor quality thumbnails

Tags: php, imagemagick

Well, just noticed my imagick is producing blurry / poor quality thumbnails. Couldn't find a piece of code that I need to correct in order to make thumbs better quality. Any suggestions? It all happens in a PHP function below. Also 2 image samples are below as well.

```
try {

$image = new Imagick($picfile);

if ($image->getImageColorspace() == \Imagick::COLORSPACE_CMYK) {
 $image->transformimagecolorspace(\Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB);
}

Imagick::setResourceLimit (6, 1);


// hypothetical new h and w
$new_w = round($o_height * $maxwidth / $maxheight);
$new_h = round($o_width * $maxheight / $maxwidth);

$ratio=round(($o_width/$o_height), 2);

if($ratio < 1.25){$go_vertical=true;}

if($o_width > $o_height && !$go_vertical){ // horizontal
    $image->cropThumbnailImage($maxwidth, $maxheight);



    $image->writeImage($path); $pathe=1;
}

if($o_width <= $o_height || $go_vertical){ // vertical
    $image2 = new Imagick();

    $image2->newImage($new_w, $o_height+2, "white");


    $x = round(abs(($new_w - $o_width) / 2))-1;

    echo $mode." x=".$x." IMAGE (".$new_w.", ".$o_height.")<br />";
    $image2->compositeImage($image, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, $x, 0);

    $image2->cropThumbnailImage($maxwidth, $maxheight);

    // Strip out unneeded meta data
    $image->stripImage();

    $image2->writeImage($path);
    $image2->destroy(); $pathe=2;
}
$image->destroy();
```

As images do not directly insereted here, here are links:

Good example: https://www.comfyco.com/temp/b/good.jpg

Bad example: https://www.comfyco.com/temp/b/bad.jpg

It doesn't look drastically different here but on actual website it's pretty bad sometimes. Any advice what parameter / line to add to make those thumbnails look better?

Thanks!

Comment: What image format is the input? If PDF, then you should set a larger density before reading the PDF. Output JPGs may capture an input JPG quality value. So perhaps reset the quality to some reasonable value or the ImageMagick default value of 92 before saving to output JPG.

Comment: Oh, forgot to tell. JPEG only. Just JPEG for upload and few JPEGs are generated as main picture + thumbnails of different sizes.

Comment: OK, then set the output quality before saving to some reasonable value as needed for acceptable quality. IM default is 92. You may be getting low quality values from your input JPG.